# Displaying the count of comments in the feed

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, cell

I have an Instagram like feed with pictures shown one at a time in each cell. You can press on them and get directed to a `commentTBV`. Here is where I have all the comments underneath the post and they get counted correctly in this View.

```
var commentsArray = [FotoComment]()

is the array holding the comments
```

kommentarArray is the array i want to fill with the assignArray func so i can use it to display the amount of counts.

```
var kommentarArray = [FotoComment]()
```

[FotoComment] is my struc I use for my comments

What I want is that already in the feed the `commentArray.count` will show the correct number of comments.

```
func assignArray() {
    let otherVC = CommentTableViewController()
    kommentarArray = otherVC.commentsArray
```

print(kommentarArray.count)
    }

This way I get access from my feed to the array of comments in the `CommentTBVC`.

My cell is:

```
cell.kommentarZähler.text = "Kommentare: \(kommentarArray.count)"
```

But it always shows 0 even though it already has 5 comments and it correctly displayed on the `CommentTBV`.

M complete code for MemesTableViewConbtroller (the feed)

```
import UIKit
```

import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseDatabase

class MemesTableViewController: UITableViewController {

```
var kommentarArray = [FotoComment]()
var dataBaseRef : FIRDatabaseReference!
var storageRef : FIRStorageReference!
var posts = [PostMitBild]()
var segmentedControl : HMSegmentedControl!





override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
  assignArray()


 segmentedControl = HMSegmentedControl(sectionTitles: ["Top Heute", "Beliebteste", "Neue"])
  segmentedControl.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 300, height: 60)
    segmentedControl.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    segmentedControl.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white]
    segmentedControl.borderColor = UIColor.brown
    segmentedControl.tintColor = UIColor.black
    segmentedControl.selectionIndicatorColor = UIColor.gray


    segmentedControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(getter: MemesTableViewController.segmentedControl), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
    tableView.tableHeaderView = segmentedControl

 segmentedAction()
}



func segmentedAction() {
    if segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {



        let postRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("MemesBilder")


        postRef.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            var newPost = [PostMitBild]()
            for post in snapshot.children {

                let Post = PostMitBild(snapshot: post as! FIRDataSnapshot)
                newPost.insert(Post, at: 0)

            }

            self.posts = newPost
            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                self.tableView.reloadData()


            }

            }, withCancel: { (error) in
                print(error.localizedDescription)
        })



    }

}



//------------------------------------------


override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {


    if FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser == nil {

        let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Login")
        self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)


    }


}






override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "postCell", for: indexPath) as! PostTableViewCell

    if let seconds = posts[indexPath.row].postDate {
         let timestamp = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: seconds)

        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy  HH:mm"
        cell.uploadDatum.text = dateFormatter.string(from: timestamp as Date)


    }

        cell.kommentarZähler.text = "Kommentare: \(kommentarArray.count)"
        cell.usernameTextField.text = posts[indexPath.row].username
        cell.postContent.text = posts[indexPath.row].content



        storageRef = FIRStorage.storage().reference(forURL: posts[indexPath.row].userImageUrlString)
        storageRef.data(withMaxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024, completion: { (data, error) in
            if error == nil {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    if let data = data {
                        cell.UserImageView.image = UIImage (data: data)
                    }
                }

            }else {
                print(error?.localizedDescription)
            }
        })

        let storageRef2 = FIRStorage.storage().reference(forURL: posts[indexPath.row].PostImageUrlString)
        storageRef2.data(withMaxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024, completion: { (data, error) in
            if error == nil {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    if let data = data {

                        cell.postImageView.image = UIImage (data: data)
                    }

                }
            }else {
                print(error?.localizedDescription)
            }
        })

        return cell



}



//done!!!! ------------------------------------------


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
      tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)


        let ref = posts[indexPath.row].ref
        ref!.removeValue()

        posts.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)

    }
}




override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    var numberOfRows = 0
    switch segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex {
    case 0 :  numberOfRows = posts.count

    case 1: numberOfRows = posts.count

    default: break


    }

    return numberOfRows
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 420.00
}




override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
        if segue.identifier == "addComment" {
            let vc = segue.destination as! CommentTableViewController
            let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!

            vc.selectedPosts = posts[indexPath.row]
        }

    }
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "addComment", sender: self)
    }
    if segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "addComment", sender: self)
    }
    if segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 2 {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "addComment", sender: self)
    }
}

func assignArray() {

    let otherVC = CommentTableViewController()
    kommentarArray = otherVC.commentsArray

    print(kommentarArray.count)
}
```

}

The code for the CommentTableViewController ( where i want to get the count of comments from the array var commentsArray = FotoComment which is already working on this TableView)

```
import UIKit
```

import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseStorage

class CommentTableViewController: UITableViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var komentarZähler: UILabel!




@IBOutlet weak var UserImageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var usernameTextField: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var postImageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var postContent: UITextView!



var dataBaseRef : FIRDatabaseReference!
var storageRef : FIRStorageReference!
var commentsArray = [FotoComment]()
var selectedPosts:PostMitBild!



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    configurePost()




    let commentRef = selectedPosts.ref!.child("Kommentare")

    commentRef.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        var newComments = [FotoComment]()
        for item in snapshot.children {
            let neuerKommentar = FotoComment(snapshot: item as! FIRDataSnapshot)
            newComments.insert(neuerKommentar, at: 0)

        }
        self.commentsArray = newComments
        self.tableView.reloadData()

        }, withCancel: { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
    })


}
@IBAction func addComment(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    let alertView = UIAlertController(title: "Kommentar", message: "Füge einen Kommentar hinzu", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    alertView.addTextField { (textfield) in
        textfield.placeholder = "Einen neuen Kommentar hinzufügen"

    }


    let sendCommentAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Kommentieren", style: .default) { (action) in
        let textfield = alertView.textFields!.first!

        let comment = FotoComment(content: textfield.text! , postId: self.selectedPosts.postId , username: (FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.displayName!) , userImageUrlString: String(describing: FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.photoURL!), postDate: (NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970))

        let commentRef = self.selectedPosts.ref!.child("Kommentare").childByAutoId()
        commentRef.setValue(comment.toAnyObject())
    }


    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Abbrechen", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
    alertView.addAction(sendCommentAction)
    alertView.addAction(cancelAction)
    self.present(alertView, animated: true, completion: nil)

}


// 2----------------------------------------------

func configurePost() {

    usernameTextField.text = selectedPosts.username
    postContent.text = selectedPosts.content


    storageRef = FIRStorage.storage().reference(forURL: selectedPosts.userImageUrlString)
    storageRef.data(withMaxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024, completion: { (data, error) in
        if error == nil {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if let data = data {
                    self.UserImageView.image = UIImage (data: data)
                }
            }

        }else {
            print(error?.localizedDescription)
        }
    })
    let storageRef2 = FIRStorage.storage().reference(forURL: selectedPosts.PostImageUrlString)
    storageRef2.data(withMaxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024, completion: { (data, error) in
        if error == nil {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if let data = data {

                    self.postImageView.image = UIImage (data: data)
                }

            }
        }else {
            print(error?.localizedDescription)
        }
    })

}






override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
      komentarZähler.text = "Kommentare: \(commentsArray.count)"
    return commentsArray.count


}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "commentCell", for: indexPath) as! CommentTableViewCell

    if let seconds = commentsArray[indexPath.row].postDate {
        let timestamp = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: seconds)

        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy  HH:mm:ss"
        cell.uploadDatum.text = dateFormatter.string(from: timestamp as Date)


    }



    cell.usernameTextField.text = commentsArray[indexPath.row].username
    cell.postContent.text = commentsArray[indexPath.row].content


    storageRef = FIRStorage.storage().reference(forURL: commentsArray[indexPath.row].userImageUrlString!)
    storageRef.data(withMaxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024, completion: { (data, error) in
        if error == nil {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if let data = data {
                    cell.UserImageView.image = UIImage (data: data)
                }
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }


        }else {
            print(error?.localizedDescription)
        }



    })
```

return cell
}

}

[this is how i safe my data in firebase. I want to update the number of comments (kommentarAnzahl which is currently 0) every time a comment is added to the post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVNx8.jpg)

Comment: Which is your main array? You have two arrays namely `kommentarArray` and `commentsArray` and your function seems to be copying one over to the next one hence you end up having two arrays holding the same data.. My guess is `commentsArray` is your main one hence use its count as your cell's text and get rid of the `assignArray` function

Comment: my Main array holding all the comments is : var commentsArray = [FotoComment](). KommentarArray is on the feedTBV and there is the place where i try to get the count to.  I try to have the same data in kommentarArray ( the new one) and commentsArray(the one holding the correct number of Comments) but it is just showing 0 as it counts.

Comment: and is that what you use to print your contents with?

Comment: My goal is to have kommentarArray equal commentsArray so i can just let it count and display it in the cell. It works on the commentTBV but not in the feedTBV

Comment: Inside your `assignArray` function, have you checked the size of `commentsArray` and `kommentarArray` after assigning?

Comment: I have print(kommentarArray.count) in it, yes but it shows 0 on the feed while e.g 3 in the commentTBV

Comment: Can you update your answer with your code for `FeedTBV` along with `CommentTBV`as well?

Comment: I wanted your entire class code.. Post the code for the classes `FeedTBV` and `CommentTBV`

Comment: I updated my entire post, hope we will find a solution now :)

Comment: Just to confirm, these tableviews are in two separate views of your app right? Because if this is the case then once you leave `CommentTableViewController`, then your `commentsArray` is removed from memory hence going to `MemesTableViewController`, `kommentarArray` is pretty much copying an empty array.

Comment: yes they are 2 different views in my app. And how do i fix that? I have absolutely no clue ...

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert your Array count to string value to display in cell.

Try this Code,

```
cell.kommentarZähler.text = String("Kommentare:",kommentarArray.count)
```

I hope this will work for You.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work out for me :/ . It is also saying init has been renamed to init(describing:) . I changed it still doesn't work .

Comment: which swift version you are using?

Comment: I am using swift 3.0

Answer (score 0):

So you have two separate view controllers namely `CommentTableViewController` and `MemesTableViewController` consisting of `commentsArray` and `kommentarArray` resepctively. These arrays are of class-scope meaning that once you get outside of your class; for this case it would be leaving the view, then they would be deallocated. Once you enter the view, they'll be re-created again and filled with values.

Since you want to get the number of elements in `commentsArray`, I'd recommend you create a *static* variable which would keep track of this. When you make something static you're pretty much making it accessible throughout your entire app/program and changes made to it are reflected across the entire app. In other words, a memory block is reserved to store your variable which will only be de-allocated once you quit the app entirely. You may think of this as an app-scope variable.

Two ways

1. **Lousy Way**

   Change your `commentsArray` definition from `var commentsArray = [FotoComment]()` to `static var commentsArray = [FotoComment]()`. By doing this, then you may access and manipulate the contents of this array from any other class. This is great if you have few elements but what happens when you have tens of thousands or even a million comments? It'll mean that we'll be walking around with huge amounts of data everywhere even when we really don't need it.
2. **Recommended Way**

   Keep your current `commentsArray` definition and add this `static var numberOfComments: Int = 0` inside your `CommentTableViewController`. Right after adding your elements to `commentsArray`, update the element tracker as shown below

   ```
   CommentTableViewController.numberOfComments = commentsArray.count
   ```

Then when you go back to your `MemesTableViewController`, you can simply delete `assignArray()`; since we have a global element counter now, and simply amend your cell to this

```
cell.kommentarZähler.text = String(CommentTableViewController.numberOfComments)
```

With this, even if you create say another class called `FriendsVC`, you can still access `numberOfComments` and even change it as well.

*PS: Since `numberOfComments` is `static`, whenever and wherever you want to access or amend it, you **MUST** always first call the class or struct in which it was defined in. For this case, it is inside `CommentTableViewController` so you need to always do `CommentTableViewController.numberOfComments` to access it; even when you are inside `CommentTableViewController` itself. Always remember that.*

Comment: hey thanks for the answer! It kinda works, which means that it now shows the number of comments but only from 1 picture (e.g: 3) and shows then 3 comments for all, when i press on a different one ( e.g:1) and go back nothing changes but if i add one comment ( now 2 ) then it shows 2 comments for every cell. I need it to be specific on each cell.

Comment: and when I enter the View in the App, it always starts with the count of 0. Only changes after i pressed on a specific cell

Comment: @Zash__ I don't really understand what you mean..Can you post like a gif that visualizes the issue? Plus if my answer resolved your first issue, please up vote and accept as answer :)

Comment: is shows the same number of comments for every cell, not how many each cell may have. its always the same number

Comment: So each cell has a different number of comments?

Comment: yes depends on the cell how many people will comment. i need it to display the number of comments from each cell individually

Comment: So what exactly does each cell consist of? And in what tableview class are these cells been loaded from?

Comment: the cell consists of the user picture, the uploaded image, and the text written + the upload datum and now i want to add the sepcific amount of comments to each cell

Comment: Okay but does each cell represent like a topic or something? Am asking so as I may understand why each cell needs to have a different amount of comments

Comment: yes each cell reprents a single uploaded picture like when u post a pic on instagram each of your pics has a certain number of comments and likes, this is the goal

Comment: Okay now I understand what you're doing.. If that's the case then I would advice you encapsulate number of comments inside your Post class and add a number of comments node in your Post Firebase node.. With this, you'd simply have to keep track of it everytime a new comment is added to a post.. Plus when you setup your Table view cell, you'd simply do cell.kommentarZähler.text = String(commentsArray[indexPath.row].numberOfComments)

Comment: So now i am so far that if you post a comment, the comment counter is 0. But how do i get it counting up, if a new comment was posted? commentRef.child("kommentarAnzahl").udateChildValues(["kommentarAnzahl" : 1]) was my try but it doesn't work out. The thing is, that "kommentarAnzahl" is created in the postModel, but how do i update it now because my function of addComment is a row deeper in the databaseTree in the section : Kommentare.

Comment: So if i post a pic my main section has : postImageUrl, content, users ... . If i create a comment, this post gets a new section Called "Kommentare". When I comment, it loads the informations from the comment in the section : upload date, userUrl, userImage. So my addCommentButton works in the deeper section of the tree, how do i change the count in the upper (or main) part of the tree?

Comment: @Zash__ I strongly believe my answer helped with your initial question so I don't know why you decided to revoke it. As far as your current issue goes, its hard to help you without seeing your project and understanding your current Firebase structure. I'd recommend you add a Github link along with your current database structure or post another question which thoroughly explains your current issue.

Comment: unfortunately it did not help me. i will update my post now :)